# How do I apply materials to instances (alt+d) objects simultaneously?

Tags: materials, instances

I have applied materials simultaneously to individual objects with ctrl+l / materials, but the ald+d objects do not allow or show the applied materials.  How do I apply a material, as I cannot even apply it to one? except the shift+d objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add materials go as you would for other objects. Material properties/new or brows.
The material of a Alt D object is always linked by data until you change it under the material properties shown in the image below to object. 
Thank you Robin!
[image]

Comment: You can choose to associate materials with the Object, as opposed to its mesh (Data), if you want to. (Bottom right of the materials list for a selected object). So Alt-D objects whose Data is linked can have separate materials. But I confess, I still don't get what's up with the OP?